# Fullcalendar v4 resource timeline not taking full width when parent container resizes

Tags: html, css, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using FullCalendar in a react project and have a side bar to the left; when I hide my sidebar the resource timeline expands, but it doesn't occupy its full width. See the image below, I get the blank space (B) on the right.

I have added a click listener to the hamburger button, so that whenever it's clicked, it calls calendar.updateSize, but this doesn't seem to fix my issue.
I tried instead of adding a click event listener to the hamburger, to add a mutation observer on the parent div for whenever its class that makes the side bar hide/show changes, and in the callback I call updateSize, this doesn't work, but if I open the devTools and set a debugger after updateSize, can click on the hamburger, the resizing occurs perfectly. I don't know why it works with the devtool opens and the debugger.

Something interesting that happens as well  is that when I switch to a different view such as dayGridMonth and then switch back to resourceTimeline, the resourceTimeiline adjusts its width properly, and fits perfectly.

[image]

Any ideas on how to I could fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Without any code (or better still, a runnable example), it's pretty much impossible to be sure what the issue could be. At a guess, check you haven't got any CSS which is accidentally interfering with the rendering of the calendar. Remove all custom CSS, even including fullCalendar themes, and run it with the default CSS supplied with the calendar, and see if you still have an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a 100ms delay after the click listener fires or mutation observer emits a value for the sidebar viw change but before the `updateSize()` function runs.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {...

height: 'parent',

...

});